# What concept should I know when I want to build a sandbox for web system in order to allow other people to inject the code

Tags: ruby, sandbox

I want to build a sandbox for my web application in order to allow people to inject their code. This application has some features similar to codewar or codecademy. It will provide an online development environment to run other's code.

According to my study, the code injection must run in the sandbox.
So I wonder how to build a sandbox, and which technical concept should I know before building.

Btw, I use ruby to build my web application.

Comment: I've flagged this question as too broad since it isn't about any one particular problem. If you have some code that you're working on and have questions about it, you can post that. It also might be useful for you to look at [security.se].